# Is there a novel using a Dyson Sphere as setting?

Tags: setting, dyson-sphere

In the ringworld-novels of [Larry Niven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Niven) the author uses a giant ring around the sun as setting. The concept that is going more extrem in this direction is a Sphere around a sun. That concept is called [Dyson Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_Sphere). Does a work of SF explores this concept?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, there's a list of them at [Dyson spheres in popular culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_spheres_in_popular_culture).  The idea originated in a novel called [Star Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Maker).

Comment: Wow, what a list.

Comment: @Mnementh: I'm definitely looking forward to reading some of those.  The Ringworld itself was my favorite part of that novel.

Answer (score 11):

Bob Shaw's Orbitsville novels:

- [Orbitsville](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0575070986)
- [Orbitsville Departure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671698311)
- [Orbitsville Judgement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0575045515)

Answer (score 11):

If you don't count just the written word, one of the episodes of Star Trek: TNG does. The episode is called "Relics."

This episode was also [novelized](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671864769) by Michael Jan Friedman, and a sequel novel named [*Dyson Sphere*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671541730) was written by Charles Pellegrino and George Zebrowski.

Answer (score 7):

In [Accelerando](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerando_%28novel%29), civilizations that advance past the technological singularity tend to build concentric Dyson swarms of [computronium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computronium) around their stars, a construction known as a [matrioshka brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrioshka_brain).

Answer (score 7):

In *Iain M Banks* book, [Matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_%28novel%29) on the Shellworld of Sursamen, which is multiple concentric dyson shells built on top of each other with a artificial sun on each level and each level holding a more advanced alien race than the level below. In the core lives a super advanced alien, and on level 7 lives the parasites that lived on the shell of the advanced alien, but have advanced enough to have the their own level.

Comment: The Shellworld is not a dyson spere... a shell that completely encloses a natural star.  The Shellworld in Matter is described as planet sized.

Answer (score 7):

The  '[The Time Ships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Ships)' (1995) by Stephen Baxter has the most interesting depiction of a Dyson Sphere I have read in Science Fiction. The novel is a sequel to the classic ‘The Time Machine’ (1895) by H. G. Wells (where there are no Dyson Spheres).

A more recent book with a memorable Dyson Swarm is ‘[House of Suns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Suns)’ (2008)  by Alastair Reynolds.

Answer (score 6):

The Halo universe has Dyson Spheres. The setting of Halo:Wars was a Dyson Sphere.

Answer (score 6):

In ["Implied Spaces", by Walter Jon Williams](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597801518), there are several Dyson spheres, although they are each in their own closed universe, reachable only by wormhole so it's maybe not your run-of-the-mill Dyson sphere.

Answer (score 4):

The ones that come to mind, are:

- [Ring of Charon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_of_Charon)
- [The Shattered Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shattered_Sphere)

A gravity pulse from a research station awakens an alien buried in the moon who opens a wormhole and takes Earth elsewhere.  And the chaos that ensues.

Turns out there is a species that grabs planets, and brings them into solar systems where they have already built Dyson Spheres.

Great series.  By [Roger Allen Macbride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_MacBride_Allen)

Answer (score 2):

Already many good answers... I'll just throw out the **Virga** series by Schroeder, starting with the first book in the series, *Sun of Suns*.  It is a fantastic series, with each book continuing the story, focusing on a different main character.